# I am trying to map an Amazon EC2 drive to a local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to map an Amazon EC2 instance to my local machine. I have read that it is possible via VPN but I need it to work without a VPN. Essentially I would like to make drives in the EC2 instance available similar to the way DropBox folders are available. I know that I could just use Dropbox but I am trying to find a way to do this using just a local machine running Windows 7 and an EC2 server using Windows Server 2008. If it is easier, I can use Windows Server 2012.

Comment: You mention Dropbox, so you might want to look into Amazon S3 which is a similar service. Otherwise I believe you are going to need to use the VPN.

Answer (score 4):

Your request is to make a volume from an Amazon EC2 instance (eg the `D:` drive) available on your local (non-EC2) computer. This is, in fact, no different to sharing drives between normal computers -- you can 'share' a drive and then connect to it.

However, I would **recommend against** doing this *across the Internet* because your drive would effectively be accessible to the entire Internet. You can secure it with a Username/Password, you could even restrict access to a range of IP addresses, but it's probably not the best way to do things. It would also be relatively slow -- computers normally expect "local" network drives rather than far-distant ones.

I'd like to suggest a couple of alternatives:

**Store files on Amazon S3**

You could use Amazon S3 as the "middle" service between your machines. Use tools such as [Cloudberry Drive](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/amazon-cloud-storage-online-hard-drive.aspx) or [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) to 'mount' Amazon S3 as a drive. You can then save to S3 as if it were a local disk, and the files would instantly 'appear' to the other computer. (DropBox [actually uses Amazon S3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PE4gwstWhmc) to store data.)

**Use the AWS CLI**

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) has a `aws s3 cp` command that lets you easily copy files to/from Amazon S3. You can even `sync` between a local directory and S3. It's an easy way to move data.

**Bottom line:** Have a think about *why* you want to share drives, and there might be an easier way to share data and actually sharing drives.

Comment: First I want to say thank you for your time helping me out. Second, the reason that we want to map an EC2 drive to a local machine is so that employees can have access to a drive but so that administration can give and revoke access to that network accessible drive. We want to host it with AWS because VPN into our local network and subsequent access to local drives only works intermittently (we have poor internet connections here on site). I have mapped another drive to the EC2 instance but I still can't map it to my local machine. Thanks again for any help you can give.

Comment: I would say that your use case (giving employees a shared storage service) is not appropriately served by "sharing a drive from Amazon EC2". This is not an appropriate way to provide shared disk storage. Given that users are remote (which adds latency to connections), it would be better to use a replication-type of sharing such as Box.Net or DropBox, or even a virtual disk technology like Cloudberry Drive or Expandrive. Those products do not expect continuous, perfect connections to a central 'drive', so they much better can handle connectivity problems.