# Is it possible to map a EC2 drive to a local drive with a letter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In one of our client scenario each laptop running a client software has to have a mapped S:\ drive.
Earlier they would map this S:\ drive to a drive in a Server on the same network like \\Server-name\$D

Now they are planning to move this server to EC2 in AWS. Is it possible to map the drive from EC2 server in local machine?

Local machine is in aclient network connected to AWS via VPN and DirectConnect.
In my research online ([I am trying to map an Amazon EC2 drive to a local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487014/i-am-trying-to-map-an-amazon-ec2-drive-to-a-local-machine)), I came to know that you can enable a VPN on EC2 server to make this happen. But I am looking for a inbuilt windows option as this is a as-is migration to AWS.

Comment: Amazon EC2 instances are just like normal computers. So, if you normally share a drive via Windows, you can continue to do this with an EC2 instance running Windows. You would need to make sure the computers are connected to the same network (eg via VPN). There might be better ways to achieve your use-case, but we can only offer such advice if you could Edit your question to provide more information. For example, _WHY_ do you desire a drive mapped to an EC2 instance -- what is it being used for? Is it mostly used for uploading or downloading files? How big are the files? Please tell us more.

Comment: Thanks John. You are right, I did a small POC to verify if the remote computer can map a drive from EC2. ( Both remote computer network and AWS are connected via DirectConnect + VPN ). Agree that its not a best practice or advisable but client demands to maintain the status quo. Thanks for your answer.